# Arquivo PDF gerado fica alterado

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports

Desenvolvi um relatório no *JasperStudio* que pega algumas informações no Banco de dados e também alguns parâmetros que são passados via campos de *Inputs*, quando estou testando a aplicação em minha estação, o PDF é gerado corretamente, porém quando estou executando a mesma aplicação no servidor de desenvolvimento o arquivo PDF fica com partes faltando e desconfigurado.

*Localhost* o arquivo sai com o seguinte Cabeçalho **(Forma correta)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando executado no servidor de desenvolvimento fica assim **(Forma incorreta)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que poderia estar causando isso?

Comment: Com o auxilio do comentário do @GustavoFragoso, consegui descobrir o motivo pelo qual os arquivos estavam sendo gerados de forma diferentes quando o processo era executado `localhost` e quando executado no `Servidor de desenvolvimento`, o problema das palavras estarem saindo cortadas era que o o tamanho que determinei do `Static text` estava muito pequeno (o que para mim não faz sentido, já que quando executado `localhost` funcionava normalmente e não cortava nada).

Comment: E o motivo do texto da data estar saindo August é por que o servidor realmente esta em inglês, então foi entrado em acordo que a data será exibida nesse formato dd/MM/yyyy e não como o nome do mês.

Espero que isso ajude aos que tiverem uma necessidade semelhante

Comment: A questão do static text pode ocorrer quando usamos como fonte "Serif" ou "Sans Serif" dai ele vai escolher a fonte default para esses casos, que pode ser diferente para cada ambiente de desenvolvimento. Basta uma variação de tamanho mínima que ele come a palavra.